# Error while loading the Code Generator toolbox in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I installed Scilab 5.5.2 on Windows 10, and then installed the Scilab Code Generator toolbox.
However, when I start Scilab, the following message appears and I can't use the toolbox. This problem occurs for every toolbox.

```
Start Scilab Code Generator
    Version: 0.9.20190122
    Load macros
atomsLoad: An error occurred while loading 'xcos_code_generator-0.9.20190122':
    File "C:\Users\光\AppData\Roaming\Scilab\SCILAB~1.2\atoms\x64\XCOS_C~1\09E129~1.201\macros\names" does not exist or read access denied.
```

(光 is my username.)

I suppose the problem comes from "\Scilab\SCILAB~1.2" in the middle of the file path. In my computer, the only folder in "Scilab" is "scilab-5.5.2", so indeed the software cannot find the file it's looking for.

Does anyone have any ideas?
I need to use the toolbox at work soon, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Note: I'm not using the latest Scilab 6.0.2 because it fails to work on my computer. It closes immediately after I open it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by myself.

It was my user name "光" that caused the problem. I found people saying that user names in full-width characters such as Japanese sometimes cause problems like this.
The solution is to create another user account with a name in half-width characters and install Scilab in that account. (Just changing the full-width user name doesn't work because it doesn't change the filenames that already exist.)

I couldn't find the solution until today because I was searching for solutions only in the context of Scilab, not in the context of software in general.

I hope this answer helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using an outdated version of Scilab. The latest version is `6.0.2` on Windows. If the newer version doesn't work properly then that's the problem you need to fix first. To test your Scilab installation you may run it in the terminal. Find the installation folder. For me, it is `C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.2\bin` the on `cmd` go to the path and run `Scilex.exe`. If not uninstall everything and install it in a proper way. My recommendation is to uninstall the old Scilab you already have. Then:

- [Install Chocolatey package manager](https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation)
- Open PowerShell as Admin and run `choco update all -y`, once in a while update your packages this way.
- run `choco install Scilab -y`
- then open the Scilab software
- run the `atomsInstall("xcos_code_generator")` in the console
- runt the `atomsLoad("xcos_code_generator")` to make sure your package is installed properly. You should see this as a result:

```
--> atomsInstall("xcos_code_generator")
Scanning repository http://atoms.scilab.org/6.0 ... Done

 ans  =

!xcos_code_generator  0.9.201901  user  SCIHOME\atoms\x64\xcos_code_generator\0.9.201901  I  !


--> atomsLoad("xcos_code_generator");

Start Scilab Code Generator
    Version: 0.9.20190122
    Load macros
    Load help
    Load demos
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed answer, Foad. I was glad that somebody cared about my problem.  
Actually, I just solved the problem now.  
It was my user name "光" that caused the problem. I found people saying that user names in full-width characters such as Japanese sometimes cause problems like this.  
I couldn't find the solution until today because I was searching for solutions only in the context of Scilab, not in the context of software in general.  
  
I'm sorry for your trouble. I should have searched more before I asked here.  
Again, I deeply thank you for your answer.